# Can one matplotlib style file inherit values from another?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose I have a matplotlib style file `base.mplstyle` with several specifications

```
legend.fancybox: True
legend.numpoints: 1
legend.frameon: True
legend.framealpha: 0.8
legend.shadow: True
text.color: white
text.usetex: True
figure.figsize : 9, 9
```

Suppose I want to create another style file `small_figure.mplstyle`, which has all identical settings save for just one:

```
legend.fancybox: True
legend.numpoints: 1
legend.frameon: True
legend.framealpha: 0.8
legend.shadow: True
text.color: white
text.usetex: True
figure.figsize : 2, 2 # <--- the only difference
```

Instead of copy-pasting a bunch of parameter values, is there any easy way to tell `small_figure.mplstyle` to inherit defaults from `base.mplstyle`? I'm thinking something concise, like

```
# This is not a valid .mplstyle file    
plt.style.use("base")
figure.figsize : 2, 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Style sheets are designed to be combined, so you can set up the styles you want to combine in list form. Note, however, that they will be overridden by the values of the more right-handed styles.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use(['base', 'small_figure'])
```

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea. Also interesting to know that the order of the list matters, that makes sense, but it's subtle